# Parser for GCC generated assembly

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly

I need to make some adjustments at the binary level to already GCC compiled C/C++ files. Therefore, I would like to parse the assembly file to get an in-memory representation of it with support for adding/removing instructions etc.

I have searched Google for AT&T assembly parsers and the like, but none shows up?

What are my options for parsing GCC assembly files with support for writing the modified code back out?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want. Why not use the `-S` switch to have gcc output assembly code, modify it, and then run the assembler by hand?

Comment: A *compiled binary* is very different from corresponding assembly code.  Which is it that you are actually trying to work with?

Comment: The GHC people do this by inserting markers with `volatile asm` statements and then using a complicated perl script to manipulate the assembly as text. Not sure if you want to do the same thing though.

Comment: Gnu binutils includes `gas`, the Gnu assembler. The parser and internal rep you want are there. But hacking `gas` is fairly complicated because it's designed to assemble for many processors.  I presume you're only interested in one.

Comment: @Gene - I want the x86 parser.

Comment: @BenSteffan - this is exactly what I want, but I need to parse the .s file to do this programatically.

Comment: @Shuzheng what do you mean by 'parse'? Do you want a program to automatically make some modifications? Or do you want to make the modifications manually and have the assembling done automatically (in which case a shell script would probably suffice)?

Comment: I want to a program to make the modifications. Therefore I need a in-memory representation of the file with nodes representing instructions.

Comment: Have the assembling done is just a single command; why would I need a shell script for that?